# Process.Start in C# The system cannot find the file specified error

Tags: c#

This is a silly and tricky issue that I am facing.

The below code works well (it launches Calculator):

```
ProcessStartInfo psStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
psStartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe";

Process ps = Process.Start(psStartInfo);
```

However the below one for SoundRecorder does not work.  It gives me "The system cannot find the file specified" error.

```
ProcessStartInfo psStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
psStartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe";

Process ps = Process.Start(psStartInfo);
```

I am able to launch Sound Recorder by using Start -> Run -> "c:\windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe" command.

Any idea whats going wrong?

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015 and using Windows 7 OS.

**UPDATE 1**:  I tried a `File.Exists` check and it shows me MessageBox from the below code:

```
if (File.Exists(@"c:\windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe"))
{
    ProcessStartInfo psStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psStartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe";

    Process ps = Process.Start(psStartInfo);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("File not found");
}
```

Comment: For safetey, capitalize the path correctly. `"C:\Windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe"`. Have you made sure to look in the explorer that the file exists? What does `File.Exists()` from `System.IO` say?

Comment: both the codes works fine for me.

Comment: You could do a `if(File.Exists(@"c:\windows\system32\soundrecorder.exe")` to make sure the file is there before trying to start the process.

Comment: Mine is 64-bit Windows 7.   @Rakitić are you using 64-bit OS too?

Comment: yes, mine is 64-bit as well.

Comment: Its going crazy. Please check Update 1 in my original question.

Comment: try this line `ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\soundrecorder.exe");` as said by @dxiv

Comment: @Rakitić - I still get "File not found" error with the above SysWOW64 path

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Most likely your app is 32-bit, and in 64-bit Windows references to `C:\Windows\System32` get transparently redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` for 32-bit apps. `calc.exe` happens to exist in both places, while `soundrecorder.exe` exists in the true `System32` only.

When you launch from `Start / Run` the parent process is the 64-bit `explorer.exe` so no redirection is done, and the 64-bit `C:\Windows\System32\soundrecorder.exe` is found and started.

From [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx):

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64.

---

**[ EDIT ]**  From the same page:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32.

So the following would work to start `soundrecorder.exe` from the (real) `C:\Windows\System32`.

```
psStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\soundrecorder.exe";
```

Comment: Interesting!  Whats the workaround here?  I want to run the in-built Sound Recorder application from my C#

Comment: And here is the Microsoft KB article which talks about SYSNATIVE documentation.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942589

Comment: It baffles one that, to this day, the "distinction" between 32-bit Windows and 64-bit Windows continues to pose untold engineering challenges to Microsoft.  The proper solution is beneath trivial.

Comment: Another fix seems to be just switching to x64 in configuration manager

Answer (score 13):

Old thread but providing one more possible case

In my case i was using arguments inside *Process.Start*

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\MyAppFolder\\MyApp.exe -silent");
```

I changed it to

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\MyAppFolder\\MyApp.exe");
info.Arguments = "-silent";
Process.Start(info)
```

Then it worked.

Comment: It helped. Also you can pass arguments in `Start` method: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start($"{pathToExe}", someArgs);`

Answer (score 3):

One more case, similar to [Ranadheer Reddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162902/645511), but different enough to trip me up for awhile.

I was making a simple mistake. I had this:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\MyAppFolder\\MyApp.exe ");
info.Arguments = "-silent";
Process.Start(info);
```

See that space after the end of the path to the app? Yeah. It doesn't like that. It will not find your file if you include that.

The solution was to remove the extraneous space. Then it worked.

This is an easy enough mistake to make if you're converting an app from starting processes by launching `"cmd.exe /c MyApp.exe -silent"` to running `"MyApp.exe"` directly instead, which is what I was doing. I hope recording my misfortune here will help future developers.