# Process.start cannot find java, even with absolute path

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a difficult time getting `Process.start` to acknowledge that Java exists, even when I use an absolute path.

`Process.Start(@"c:\windows\system32\java.exe");`

produces

> Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)
>      at Transpiler.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\GIT\MainLine\transpiler2\Program.cs:line 80

Even though java.exe *does* exist at that location.

Comment: I saw other comments indicating that that's a normal place for java to be installed to.  Nonetheless, `java` alone doesn't work either, even though it's in my path and has been for years.

Comment: Moreover typing `c:\windows\system32\java.exe` in a separate `cmd` window causes java to run fine :\

Comment: Weird, does process monitor shed any extra info? Also try without the filepath ie `Process.Start("java.exe");` as the System32 folder is the default path.

Comment: @Rob - just ran the compiled exe as administrator, no change :(

Comment: @Jeremy - none that I can see

Comment: If its a x64 system then you need to use "Sysnative" instead of "System32" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678576/process-start-in-c-sharp-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error

Comment: Pretty sure it's a permissions issue. I can reproduce it by copying in a blank file named `java.exe`. File is not present in `Directory.GetFiles()` either (however other files are).

Comment: @Jeremy - where's Sysnative?  Not sure I understand your comment

Comment: @Jeremy - my goodness.  That's ... infuriating.  Post as answer and I'll upvote & accept.

Comment: @jeremy - other fix seems to be just switching to x64 in configuration manager :-|