# C# Processes - cannot find "MultiDigiMon" exe utility

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, touch

I'm trying to launch the MultiDigiMon (Multiple digital monitors) utility as part of an automatic calibration scheme.

I can launch it manually by running "multidigimon -touch" (note: that if you don't have any touch devices it wont launch for you, but the file is still in the system32 folder). I can launch the cmd.exe utility just fine.

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\MultiDigiMon.exe", "-touch");
        Process.Start(info);
```

It will just fail with the exception (when you run it):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at CommandLineTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\-\Program.cs:line 20
```

Weirdly enough, if you run it via debug or release, it won't throw a runtime exception, it just won't open the utility.

Administrator privileges make no difference. 64-bit Windows 10.

I've tried:

[Process.Start in C# The system cannot find the file specified error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678576/process-start-in-c-sharp-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error)

[Error in Process.Start() -- The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369119/error-in-process-start-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified?rq=1)

Comment: Looking for references to that EXE on the web, I it seems (http://www.fileinspect.com/fileinfo/multidigimon-exe/) that it is a hidden system file.  Its "hidden-ness" may be getting in the way.  Microsoft probably doesn't want you to run it.

Comment: That might be true, but I need it to calibrate touch screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

So, I did some testing and the reason you're getting the error "can't find the file" is because when running 'un-elevated' it's not able to find the file. I'm unsure still why you aren't able to run it elevated but I was able to run it using the code below. My config is set as "Any-CPU".

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\Sysnative\MultiDigiMon.exe", "-touch");
info.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\Sysnative\";
info.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(info);
```

---

### Original

Did you try [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38678712/3825611) on the first referenced post?

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\sysnative\MultiDigiMon.exe", "-touch");
```

Comment: Adding the `UseShellExecutive` seemed to make it work, but only on the machine with the touch interfaces (otherwise it wasn't found, but still present).

Comment: Interesting. Glad it's working for the ones you need at least. You might play with the targeting the different platforms if you run into issues on some machines.

Comment: I changed the configuration, but it made no difference. Thankfully,  its part of a tool to be deployed an imaged machine, so all the underlying hardware, OS etc is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In 64-bit Os, If you want to use exe in System32 folder, see this:

```
PVOID OldValue = NULL;
BOOL bRet = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue);
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\MultiDigiMon.exe"), _T(" -touch"), NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
if (bRet)
{
    Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue);
}
else
{
    LOG_ERROR("Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection failed!!!");
}
OldValue = NULL;
```